# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "openai.completions is not a function"

Tags: typescript, next.js, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to run the test code in the tutorial https://harishgarg.com/writing/building-a-chat-app-with-gpt-3-reactjs-and-nextjs-a-step-by-step-guide/ and I get

> TypeError: openai.completions is not a function

from the following code I put in my.js and run with "node my.js" in git bash window on Windows 10

```
    const openai = require('openai');
    openai.apiKey = "api-key";
    openai.completions({
         engine: "text-davinci-003",
                   prompt: "Hello, how are you?",
                   max_tokens: 32,
                   n: 1,
                   stop: ".",
                   temperature: 0.5,
                  }).then((response) => {
                      console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
    });
```

I have tried various alternate code snippets from OpenAI docs and some suggested in other questions but have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: make sure you are using the right version

Comment: Using openai version 3.1.0

Comment: I am wondering if the environment is expecting Typescript but the sample code is just javascript? The install for create-next-app asked if Typescript was wanted and I just accepted it by default. Not sure how to override that option in the create-next-app install it asks No/Yes, typing n or no doesn't seem to override.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the OpenAI package.

**Python:**

`pip install --upgrade openai`

**NodeJS:**

`npm update openai`

Close the terminal and open it again. Run the code. The error should disappear.

Comment: it says response is not defined.

Comment: @Sumit I need to see your code. Ask a new question, and I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score -2):

```
const openai = require('openai');

async function generateCompletion() {
  try {
    const response = await openai.completions({
         engine: "text-davinci-003",
                   prompt: "Hello, how are you?",
                   max_tokens: 32,
                   n: 1,
                   stop: ".",
                   temperature: 0.5,
                  }).then((response) => {
                      console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}


generateCompletion();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).